# Does netbeans IDE contain a virus?

Tags: netbeans-8

I was looking at installing Netbeans 8.2 for working with PHP, java, HTML, etc. for various projects. However, when I download the installer both firefox and chrome inform me that the installer contains a virus. Is this a real problem?

Comment: The real Netbeans installer does not contain a virus. It's likely that you downloaded it from a site other than the official one and didn't get the real installer.

Comment: I downloaded it from netbeans.org

Comment: Works for me with Windows 7, Windows 10 and Firefox 51

Comment: I have got the same warning. Windows 7 and Firefox 51

Comment: I have the same issue as the OP, I tried downloading the NetBeans PHP bundle on Chrome/Win 10 in recent days, I get the same 'virus' warning. Also get the warning with Firefox. Downloaded from netbeans.org.

Comment: I am leaning towards the false positive. I scanned the file and computer repeatedly with bit defender and nothing.

Comment: I have this issue too... I scanned it with kaspersky and it's safe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It must be a false positive.
The SHA-256 checksum matches with the provided one in [netbeans.org](https://netbeans.org/downloads/start.html?platform=linux&lang=en&option=php&bits=x64)

Comment: If the download file were compromised, why couldn't the checksum be as well?  I'm not saying it is, I'm just wondering why having a matching checksum is somehow proof of anything?

Answer (score 1):

It's a false positive, plus you can also download a zip file from netbeans.org/downloads/zip.html

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded and installed version 8.2 on windows 10 64 bit twice and the OS gave me this message both times but I ignored it thinking that the OS just must have had a problem with how the package was signed. Later Windows defender removed two trojans. I would say there is a high likely-hood that the installer really does contain a virus and the netbeans team should look into it.

Answer (score -1):

I went through and downloaded all the version of NetBeans (using chrome) and didn't get any issues.

The website I downloaded them from is https://netbeans.org/downloads/

Comment: Sigh I tried downloading it again. It is still giving me the error. I can override and get the file. Just concerning that I keep getting (It is my favorite IDE). I will operate under the assumption my browsers don't know what they are talking about and scan my computer to be sure.

Comment: To be extra safe go ahead and download it (don't run it) and scan it in-particular with your antivirus.

Answer (score -1):

I have(had) the same issue, perhaps it is getting blocked because it contains Java.

As the OP knows, there is the option to right-click 'Unblock' it...

It's definitely a false positive; I also downloaded it from 'netbeans.org'...