# Does Apache Netbeans still contain ransomware?

Tags: java, netbeans

Last night I installed Netbeans to check a school project I did years ago. It didn't seem to run so I tried uninstalling it but then Windows Defender popped up saying that a ransomware needed access to uninstall it completely, and blocking it would cancel the uninstallation. I clicked allow and uninstalled the IDE.

After that, I read that Github detected that ransomwares were in Netbeans in 2020. I want to know if this is still true up to now and if I'm the only one who's encountering this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have misunderstood the problem.  From my reading, the problem wasn't ransomware in Netbeans itself.  The problem was that ransomware was spreading via booby-trapped Netbeans projects that had been uploaded to Github.

Netbeans itself never contained any form of malware.  Rather, the bad guys had found a way to propagate malware which involved Netbeans projects ... and developers not taking the appropriate steps to validate the projects they downloaded from Github.

There were a couple of significant vulnerabilities in Apache Netbeans (CVE-2019-17560, CVE-2020-11986) in the last couple of years.  Both have been fixed.  I have not seen any evidence (or claims of evidence) that these are in any way implicated in the above problem.

Having said that, if you are uncomfortable using Netbeans, use a different IDE.

Sources:

- StackOverflow Q&A - [Does netbeans IDE contain a virus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42494919/does-netbeans-ide-contain-a-virus/42659145) ... which says this is a false positive in Windows Defender<sup>1</sup>.
- [GitHub warns Java developers about malware infecting NetBeans projects](https://developer-tech.com/news/2020/jun/01/github-java-developers-malware-infecting-netbeans-projects/)

---

<sup>1 - Given that other AVs have been pinged for doing this to Netbeans, I am inclined to think that it was actually an inaccurate report, or report that a number of AV vendors misconstrued, that lead the them flag Netbeans as malware.  Either way, you might want to check that your Windows Defender's database is up to date.</sup>